# Clean 301 redirects using an .htaccess that also removes index.php

Tags: htaccess, redirects, rewrite

I've got a somewhat standard `.htaccess` for removing `index.php` from my EE1 URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(utm_source=.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/ [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1&%1 [L]
```

What I need to do is redirect calls to a subfolder (`/store`) to a new subdomain (`store.example.com`). So I added this line at the top:

```
Redirect 301 /store http://store.example.com/
```

Unfortunately, the end result is that I get redirected to `http://store.example.com//?/store/`

I've tried a few variations, such as moving the line to the bottom, but nothing worked properly.

How can I do a 301 redirect (using `.htaccess`) without including the extra `/?/store/` bit at the end?

Comment: I'll see if I can whip up some htaccess magic for you in a few hours, not at the office yet. Pretty sure your fist parameter needs regex expression start and end delimiters.

Comment: Or actually you might need a redirect match rule, not just a redirect. Some combo of all the crap I just said.

Answer (score 1):

Try a RedirectMatch rule and see what you get:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/store/?$ http://store.example.com
```

Comment: Miniscule improvement - now I get redirected to `http://store.example.com/?/store/` (with just the one forward slash instead of two).

Comment: I hate to say it, but there is a great chance this rule is being modified by another. Cascading htaccess rules can be a pain. Would it be reasonable to post your entire htaccess file with your domain redacted?

Comment: Like, stuff like what your redirect base is, your index.php removal is, all affects how we should go about this rule set. Including any other redirect rules. I know, htaccess is a pain, but I can probably help you if I see the whole thing. If I can't, next I'll be bugging you about your environment.

Comment: What I posted in the OP _is_ my entire .htaccess. :p

Answer (score 1):

This is what we use to redirect a directory to a subdomain

```
RewriteRule ^trade* http://trade.domain.com/    [R=301,L]
```